# C++: How to create a member 2D-array of size determined at runtime

Tags: c++, c++14

I've tried to declare an empty pointer to a pointer, assign to it pointer to allocated during construction memory and iterate over it doing the assignment again, but I'm missing something. Also I wonder if it's possible to do this with the `std::array`. Attaching the code:

```cpp
// Cell.h

class Cell {
    char contents;
    bool is_free;
};
```

```cpp
// Memory.h

#include "Cell.h"
#include <cstddef>

class Memory {
public:
    Memory(std::size_t nlines, std::size_t ncols);
private:
    Cell **cells;
};
```

```cpp
// Memory.cpp

#include "Memory.h"

Memory::Memory(std::size_t nlines, std::size_t ncols):
    cells(new Cell[nlines]) // Cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'Cell **' with an rvalue of type 'Cell *'
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < nlines; ++i)
        cells[i] = new Cell[ncols];
}
```

In addition I need my array to contain Cells with values `char contents = '.', bool is_free = true` after it is initialized. Which is the best way to do it?

UPD: I've thought of creating a 2D pseudo-array using a single pointer (not a pointer to a pointer) and accessing a cell with `i*ncols + j`.

Comment: Error message for initializing cells is pretty informative here. You are trying to assign `Cell[nlines]`  (i.e. a 1D array) to something of type `Cells **` (a 2D array). You need to change this line to `cells(new Cell*[nlines])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also I'm curious if it's possible to do this with the std::array

You can not, the size of an [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is specified as a template parameter and your array is dynamically sized.

Rather than dealing with raw pointers, you should look at [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for dynamically sized arrays:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Cell>> cells{ncols, std::vector{nlines, Cell{}}};
```

The key benefit is that you avoid having to manually allocate and manage memory.

> UPD: I've thought of creating a 2D pseudo-array using a single pointer (not a pointer to a pointer) and accessing a cell with i*ncols + j.

This is a much better idea, keeping your data in a single flat vector reduces fragmentation.

```
std::vector<Cell> cells(nlines*ncols, Cell{});
```

To make access easier, you can wrap this 1D vector in a class which exposes a `operator()(std::size_t row, std::size_t col)`, that does the conversion from (row, col) indices to the location in the 1d array.

Comment: Thanks. Also I've figured that I don't have to iterate over the array and manually assign each cell. So ```new``` in c++ fills the memory with the elements with their default values?

Comment: And is there any difference between initializing default values in class declaration and its constructor?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, a code snippet would help. If you mean, is there a difference between 1) `Cell cell1;` and 2) `Cell cell2 = Cell{};`, no they produce the same result for your class.

Comment: ```struct Cell { char contents = '.'; bool is_free = true };``` and ```struct Cell { char contents; bool is_free; Cell(char contents = '.', bool is_free = true) :contents(contents), is_free(is_free) { } };```. I have a feeling they're reciprocal, but I've heard that aggregates cannot have initializers, so I'm curious if there're any more differences.

Comment: The first is a redeclaration of the struct with in-class initialised values for the members, not a construction of an object! The second is what you probably want.

Comment: I meant that the first _replaces_ the initial code, not _adds_ to it. Thanks, now I think both version will suit me.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood, in that case, the first is preferable IMO, but this is a matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write

```
Memory::Memory(std::size_t nlines, std::size_t ncols)
    :cells(new *Cell[nlines]) 
{
...
}
```

(Note the `Cell *` instead of `Cell`).

`std::array` is compile-time fixed array size only, so it is not suitable for your purpose.

I would agree to your edit. Do not an array of pointers for matrices, use the flat array approach with indexing `i*ncols + j`. This former is more difficult to work with and has higher overhead (due to many `new` calls).

If you are worried about the multiplications overhead, you could make a look-up table for `i*ncols`. But I doubt that it is worth it.